# Which would be best to use setMessage(null) or StringUtils.EMPTY?

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I need to clear the warning or say error message,which will be the best one to choose
setMessage(null)
or
by using StringUtils.EMPTY - i just want to know the exact way of using StringUtils.EMPTY,it would be helpful...

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Without seeing actual use case it is difficult to answer.  I prefer using emptyObject/NullObject instead of null. So StringUtils.EMPTY is good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `null`.

Since it's a message you might showing it some where,If you set it to `null`,it displays as `"null"`  to end user.

Try like ,

```
private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

setMessage(EMPTY_STRING );
```

on there other hand you can check with `isEmpty`  method,instead of checking `null`.

Comment: *"Do not use null"* - I would argue that is contextual.  A `null` value may have special meaning to the object it's being set to - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes agreed.I added some possible reason in below in this case. :)